# Show Service permissions programmatically

Tags: winapi, service, permissions

It is possible to get service permissions via command line:

```
C:\Users\myname>sc sdshow EventSystem

D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCR
RC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)
```

How can I get this value via C++ code and `winapi`?

Answer (score 1):

From [Service Security and Access Rights](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685981.aspx#access_rights_for_a_service) on MSDN:

> To get or set the security descriptor for a service object, use the
>   `QueryServiceObjectSecurity` and `SetServiceObjectSecurity` functions.
>   For more information, see [Modifying the DACL for a Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684215.aspx).

So there's the answer. You call `QueryServiceObjectSecurity`.

Comment: Note that `QueryServiceObjectSecurity()` will return a `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR` structure, which contains binary data. It you want the contents in a human readible string format, use `ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor()`.